# AdventureWorks2012 database missing "DimTime" table

Tags: ssis, etl, adventureworks

I am doing the **"Creating Simple ETL Package"** from **microsoft technet** tutorial. it referes to **"DimTime"** table in the database which is not available. I am aware that in the **2008 version**, "DimTime" was renamed to **"DimDate"**.

1. Does this also hold for **2012** version?
2. Does the tutorial hold for 2012 version or only the **2008 or 2088R2** version?

I tried to ask this in Microsoft Issue Tracker but no answers yet.

Comment: Did you get an answer to your question? I've just hit the same problem...

Answer (score 4):

You have to use DimDate instead of DimTime.

The DimTime table has been renamed to DimDate since the table actually contains dates rather than times.

Source:

http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AWDW2008Details

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer for #1: Yes, it does hold for the 2012 version.

For #2: The tutorial web pages have an "other versions" drop down where you can select the version of SQL Server you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use DimTime. I tried. It works.